# How to implement profile avatar in react application in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So, I am trying to develop a page using react-native. The UI for the page is below. How do I implement the profile picture icon?

[image: UI for the page]

Comment: You can use https://reactnative.dev/docs/image Image Component.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to import the **Image** using react native

```
import { Image} from 'react-native';
```

then inside your view you need to **style** it as you want

```
<Image
    style={{width: 100, height: 100}}  // required Dimensions and styling of Image
    source={require('./images/avatar.png')} // enter your avatar image path 
   />
```